# Attack multiple Trees

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

this is Mahsa

I am creating a feature that player cut multiple trees at once
I play the attack animation when a tree or multiple trees enter my trigger
but the problem is when it comes to multiple trees it won’t continue the attacking
Here’s how

```
[SerializeField] PlayerData playerData;
[SerializeField] PlayerTileCollector collector;

public List<Damageable> damageableList = new List<Damageable>();

private int attackLayerIndex;
public float damageAmount = 0.1f;


private void Awake()
{
    attackLayerIndex = playerData.playerAnimator.GetLayerIndex("Attack");

}


private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    var tree = other.gameObject.GetComponent<Damageable>();
    if(!tree) return;

     damageableList.Add(tree);

    if(tree.tag == "Tree")
    {
        playerData.axe.gameObject.SetActive(true);

        //Debug.Log("In");

        playerData.playerAnimator.SetLayerWeight(attackLayerIndex, 1f);
        playerData.playerAnimator.SetTrigger("Attack");
    }
}



private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
{
    var tree = other.gameObject.GetComponent<Damageable>();
    if(!tree) return;

     damageableList.Remove(tree);

    if(tree.tag == "Tree")
    {
        playerData.axe.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        playerData.playerAnimator.SetTrigger("Stop");
        //Debug.Log("Out");
    }
}

public void PlayerAttack()
{

    foreach(var tree in damageableList)
    {
        tree.TreeTakeDamage(damageAmount, collector);
    }

   
}
```

I was expected don't stop attacking until tree health goes zero

Comment: checking for a component and a tag seems a bit redundant in general ..have in mind that animator triggers are stackable and in case you already are in attack state it will remember the trigger and immediately pass the transition again next time

Comment: Where is PlayerAttack being called?